# Where to set up a subdomain?

Tags: subdomain, godaddy, server-setup

So I have a domain, lets say example.com, with godaddy.com.
My website is hosted for free at zymic.com.

I configured the Nameserver at godaddy with the Nameserver addresses from zymic and it works fine.

Now I want to use a subdomain like blog.example.com, and I wanna have it go to my blogger blog... I know how to do in the the blogger side, but do I have to do anything on godaddy?

Answer (score 2):

Add a CNAME on godaddy to point to your zymic hosting, or use some of godaddy's forwarding tools (http://help.godaddy.com/article/415).

Comment: If I do forwarding, when the user finally lands on my blogger blog the address bar will show myblog.blogger.com instead of blog.example.com that they originally typed correct? Thats not what I want... Is that the case if I go the "CNAME" way?

Comment: Exactly. Documentation:

http://help.godaddy.com/article/679 - and -
http://www.google.com/support/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=58317

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have to configure a sub-domain at your domain provider in the configuration section (add CNAME).

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the sub-domain in domain provider and if you have your own server for hosting website you have to configure your virtualhost in apache or whatever server your using.

Answer (score 0):

Here are Google's instructions for how to migrate to your own domain in Blogger:
http://www.google.com/support/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55373